# When should I not use a self-rendering view?

Tags: backbone.js

I've been studying [this](http://codebyexample.info/2012/03/06/backbone-baby-steps/) Backbone tutorial and came across this bit of code:

```
var LibraryView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el:$("#books"),

    initialize:function(){
        this.collection = new Library(books);
        this.render();
    },
    ...
});
```

The author explains that `this.render()` makes the view render when its constructor is called.

When would you not want the view to self-render?

Comment: I guess the answer is 'good practise'. What you have will work, but it's better to ensure the 'initialize' function has just one responsibility - initialising the view. This clarity will repay itself in time!

As for when - lots of larger SPA will initialise views at one stage, then render a base template and render the views on top of that later on. I personally think 'self-rendering views' are rarely a good idea.

Comment: I see. So when/where should the `this.collection` property be set if not when its created?

Comment: `this.collection` is perfect where it is. You'd just end up with `var lib = new LibraryView(); lib.render()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The render method does nothing more than adding HTML to the DOM by using jquery's `html` or `append` methods. Where you choose to call the render method on the view is an architectural choice.

Backbone is said to apply the MV* pattern where models are bound directly to the view.
As such, the view would render itself upon instantiation, and have the ability to render itself when the model changes.

However, Backbone leave a lot of decisions to the developer and is a flexible library. There is nothing that technically prevents you to use control objects that manage the flow of the views; as such, another object can instantiate and re-render the view as well.

```
var view = new Bb_View(); 
view.render();
```

In the end, `render` is just a method on the view, and you can define your own methods as well. An example reason why I would call custom methods on the view from outside the view, is when I keep reference to an array of views.
As an event occurs, I loop through the views, I might add some conditions, and then call the custom method on particular views based on the condition.